# Array of char* to pointer

Tags: c, pointers

How would I make a pointer to:

```
char * values [x];
```

I'm trying to pass an array of `char *` to a pointer from outside the block of code, where x can by anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointer to a pointer can do what you want.

```
char ** val ;
```

In the function definition :

```
return_type func(char ** val) {...}
```

In the function call :

```
func(&values)
```

You need to pass the address of the pointer to the function.